# Promise issue with oData File Parsing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, odata, sapui5

I try to use 'akorchev/odata2openapi' module to transform odata metadata.xml file into json. As per documentation, I have implemented the following code:

```
const o2oapi = require('odata2openapi');

function_B (content) {
  o2oapi.parse(content)  
    .then(entitySets => convert(entitySets))
    .then(swagger => console.log(JSON.stringify(swagger, null, 2)))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
 }
```

The content variable is a metadata xml stream that I can display on console. I can also see the following result when logging the parse method of function B:

```
Promise {
 { entitySets: [ [Object], [Object] ],
   version: '1.0',
   complexTypes: [],
   singletons: [],
   actions: [],
   functions: [],
   defaultNamespace: 'ZEXAMPLE_SRV',
   entityTypes: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get the final result 'from swagger' to pass to another function C.

```
function_A (content, x, y, z){
  function_C (function_B (content), x, y ,z);
}
```

I have tried to adapt my code without any success. Could you please advice?

Comment: What does `convert` do? Does it expect the contents of the `entitySets` property output by `parse`? Because you are passing it the whole object and not that property. You can log out to console inside the `then` functions and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve the issue with multiple changes. As suggested by @ethan-jewett, I had to debug the convert method to see that inputs were wrong. In addition, as suggested by @moshimoshi, I had to cascade async functions.

Here, the final code implementation of function B:

```
function_B(content) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const options = {
          host: '',
          path: ''
         };

        parse(content)  
            .then(entitySets => convert(entitySets.entitySets, options))
            .then(function(swagger) {
                var result = JSON.stringify(swagger, null, 2);
                resolve(result);
            })    
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            }); 
    });         
}
```

For function A:

```
function_A (content, x, y, z){
  function_B (content).then(result => function_C (result , x, y ,z));
}
```